# Button adds child div dynamically, and recreates the button

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a form in which the user could add both new "items" and new "categories". After each item input box, there is a button to add another input box. For each category, there are a list of inputs and an input for the category name; similarly, at the end of the category there is a button to add another category.

I have made the buttons work, but the new button that is added to the form doesn't add new input elements, only the first one does. So far I have been using this code for the javascript:

```
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><div class='form-inline' id='dynamicInput'><label  for='item'>Item #" + (counter + 1) + "</label><input type='item' class='form-control' id='item1' placeholder='Artichoke Hearts'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg' onclick='addInput('dynamicInput')'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Add</button></div>";
 document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
 counter++;

}
```

The same javascript is used for the category as well, just different function name and html. 
Here is a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/zpCjR/
(strangely that code doesn't work on jsfiddle, but does on my browser through the local machine...)??

I tried to get the elementByClassName instead but that also didn't work.

I hope this makes sense. If it isn't clear please comment and Ill try and explain it differently. I have been struggling with this for a while now. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gawazu/2/edit?html,js,output

I know people like to bash on jQuery but this is a great scenario to use it. When adding content dynamically that you want to respond to events (e.g. click) it is usually best to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). That way when you add more elements they will automatically be setup to execute your JS in response to your click events.

In the example below I listen for click events on `.addItem` buttons. When those buttons are clicked I run `addItem`. `addItem` will traverse up through the DOM to the form parent element, and then attach a new item to that element's parent (`body` in this example).

```
// Use event delegation to listen for clicks on all `.addItem` elements,
// even ones added dynamically later
$(document).on('click', '.addItem', addItem);

var counter = 1;

function addItem() {
  counter++;

  // jQuery will make `this` a reference to the element that triggered the click event (`.addItem` button)
  // Find the `.form-inline` element that is the parent of `.addItem`
  // Select the form's parent element
  var $parent = $(this).closest('.form-inline').parent();

  var html = '<div class="form-inline"><label for="item">Item #' + counter + '</label> <input type="item" placeholder="Artichoke Hearts"> <button type="button" class="addItem">Add</button></div>';

  // Append the new HTML to the form's parent element
  $parent.append(html);
}
```

Comment: jQuery is the way to go. Thanks a lot for the detailed response it helped me greatly. I'll keep working on some jQuery tutorials so I can use it more often.

Answer (score 1):

The whole problem with jsfiddle is that you must set in the upper left hand site `No wrap -in <head>` so the methods will work..If you don't the name of the method will appear as undefined in the console..I didn't change anything in the code..Just changed the `No wrap -in <head>` part and works perfectly
[image: It Works!]

EDIT :

This is the new fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/zpCjR/1/

I basically just replaced the innerHTML part with the above one in the html and it worked...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. But now the problem I was asking about is still there. If you click the second button, after adding one, that one fails to add another button. Only if you click the first button does it work